# String comparison function

Tags: c, string, function, comparison, compare

I am new to C and am trying to figure out and learn why my code isn't working. I understand that in C a string is basically an Array of each character. So I have been trying to search through the array to find the letter a and then print something if it is found. But my program keeps crashing every time I try to run it.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Display(char ch[]);

int main() {
    char c[50];
    printf("Enter String: ");
    gets(c);             
    Display(c);

    return 0;
}

void Display(char ch[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(ch)); i++) {
        if (strcmp(ch[i],"a") == 0) {
            printf( "Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my program I enter a random string for example "fdas" and press enter. Then it crashes =\

Please remember I am new to C. I am a Java programmer if that helps with any explanations.

Comment: Compile your program with warnings.

Comment: Unrelated: Forget you ever saw the function [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets), a function so vile it has been removed from the standard library.

Comment: What is the error message that is thrown on crash?

Comment: There isn't a message that appears when it crashes. The command prompt just says the program isn't working and that I need to close the program. @WhozCraig what would you suggest instead of gets()?

Comment: @Mango [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is a good alternative, or [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) if you target platforms support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
if(strcmp(ch[i],"a") == 0)
```

it should be

```
if (ch[i] == 'a')
```

and also, `sizeof(ch)` is not giving you the length of the string, for that you need `strlen()`, your `Display()` function should look like this to work

```
void Display(char *ch) {
    size_t i;
    size_t length;
    if (ch == NULL)
        return;
    length = strlen(ch);
    for (i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        if (ch[i] == 'a') {
            printf( "Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

also, using `gets()` is unsafe, and deprecated, use`fgets()`

```
fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
```

is better than `gets(c)` because it will prevent buffer overflow, note that I've used the `sizeof` operator in this case, because `c` is an array of `char` and the `sizeof` operator will give it's size in bytes, and since `1 char == 1 byte` then it works.

In the case of the `Display()` function, it's not the same because there the `sizeof` operator will give the size of the type of `ch`, and since what you really need is the count of characters that `ch` points to, so you must use `strlen()` or compute the length yourself.

Comment: So with C you can compare Strings to characters using == ?

Comment: No `ch[i]` is the `i`th character, so you compare characters to characters.

Comment: Comparing the characters worked. Thank you for the explanation